# Is there any PEP regarding a pipe operator in Python?

Tags: python, pep

It is often common to write this type of python code:

```py
def load_data():
   df_ans = get_data()
   df_checked = check_data(df_ans) # returns df_ans or raises an error
   return_dict = format_data(df_ans) 
   return return_dict
```

One could write the above like this (but it's ugly in my opinion)

```py
def load_data():
   return format_data(check_data(get_data()))
```

If this were all pandas code, one could use the .pipe method to do as follows:

```py
def load_data():
   return get_data().pipe(check_data).pipe(format_data)
```

However, there seems to be no universal way to "pipe" things in Python, something like:

```py
def load_data():
   return (get_data() |> check_data |> format_data)
```

Is there any PEP proposal for this? I could not find one.

I've seen some libraries that do operator overloading on `|` but I don't think that's what I'm looking for - I'm looking for `x {operator} y` to be the same as `y(x)` (which of course requires `y` to be callable)

Comment: `pipe`function already exists in [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe).

Comment: Awesome; I'd accept this if you submit this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a pipe operator in Python will be approved in the near future. To do that operation there is already the function [`pipe`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.pipe) in the `toolz` library.
It is not a Python built in library but is widely used.

In case you are curious the implementation is just:

```
def pipe(data, *funcs):
    for func in funcs:
        data = func(data)
    return data
```

Comment: Thank you, I've used reduce from functools in the past:

`functools.reduce(lambda x, f: f(x), [data, func1, func2, func3])`

Comment: This `pipe` breaks type checking, doesn't it?

Comment: I highly recommend [expression](https://pypi.org/project/Expression/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind decorating all functions where pipes are used with `@pipes`, you may like [robinhilliard/pipes](https://github.com/robinhilliard/pipes).

It is inspired by the Elixir syntax:

```py
@pipes
def pretty_pipe():
    print (
        range(-5, 0)
        << map(lambda x: x + 1)
        << map(abs)
        << map(str)
        >> tuple
    )  # prints ('4', '3', '2', '1', '0')
```

The `>>` works similarly to `|>` in Elixir, while `<<` is implemented to circumvent APIs like `map` and `reduce` where the right parameter is the iterables.